# Java date format for 00 days/months

Tags: java, date, zero, date-parsing, dayofmonth

I have a date as `String`, but sometimes it doesn't have valid day or month (the values are zeros, `00`).

Example:

```
String value = "03082017";
```

Then I do:

```
    String day = value.substring(0,2);
    String month = value.substring(2,4);
    String year = value.substring(4,8);

    if(day.equals("00")) {
        day = "01";
    }
    if(month.equals("00")) {
        month = "01";
    }

    value = day + month + year;
```

This works for the example `String`.

Now I have this String:

```
String value = "00092017" //ddMMyyyy
```

Then my code converts the `00` day to `01`.

This works for the pattern `ddMMyyyy`, but now is my problem: I can have different patterns: `ddMMyyyy` or `MMddyyyy` or `yyyy/dd/MM`, etc

My solution is to check first the pattern (such as `MMddyyyy`) and then I look my value `03092017` (`ddMMyyyy`) and take the numbers to my day string where is in the position dd from my pattern.

So the code has the pattern `ddMMyyyy` but value is `03092017` (`MMddyyyy`)

```
String day = "03";
.....
```

My code:

```
public void doSomething(String valueWithDate, String pattern){
    // now I become: 
    // valueWithDate = 01092017
    // pattern = ddMMyyyy

    String day = valueWithDate.substring(0,2);
    String month = valueWithDate.substring(2,4);
    String year = valueWithDate.substring(4,8);

    //Works I get my information but what is when I get other pattern/value? for example:
    // valueWithDate = 09082017
    // pattern = MMddyyyy
    // now I want my information again, but day is not on substring 0,2
}
```

Comment: why don't you just use a dateformatter?

Comment: How can you check the pattern? Any day and month smaller or equal to 12 will be valid but could be the wrong way around...

Comment: Unless this is for *educational* purpose: do **not** re-invent the wheel. Java has a ton of options to do date parsing ... and when you restrain yourself to the things added with Java8 - you get a lot of very useful stuff.

Comment: I think you are on the right track: with each entry detect what date format you have, then try to read the date from this entry.

Comment: This sounds impossible. How do you decide whether 11032017 is 11th of March or 3rd of November? In 11002017, how do you decide whether the day-of-month or the month is missing?

Comment: maybe i tell a litle bad, my englisch is not the best :/ my methode: private void parseString(String value, String pattern).. so i have the value like 01002017 and pattern like ddMMyyyy so i know the pattern and the value, but i have to convert the 00 to 01, when the pattern is MMyyyydd then i have maybe the value 11201700 now i have to change the day from 00 to 01

Comment: maybe better to understand: my methode get 2 strings: Value and pattern, when the value is 00082017 //ddMMyyyy and the pattern is ddMMyyyy now in my methode i have 3 Strings: day = month = and year = now i will fill the strings day = 00 month = 08 year = 2017 how can i do this? my example from the first post works, but what is when i get value 09002017 and pattern MMddyyyy then is it not working

Comment: updated question

Comment: You might [following example](https://gist.github.com/MenoData/14364a1bcd44468e705c3d6a0dab3d00) using my lib Time4J helpful (better in parsing and formatting than the standard). The crucial point is: 00 is interpreted as literal and not as value. Furthermore, an elegant or-syntax is possible by using the special pattern character "|".

Comment: *I can have different patterns: ddMMyyyy or MMddyyyy or yyyy/dd/MM, etc* - is 01022017 with ddMMyyyy or MMddyyyy? How do you differ these two patterns?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you're using **Java 8**, you can use the [new java.time API](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/datetime). It's easier, [less bugged and less error-prone than the old APIs](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1969442/7605325).

If you're using **Java <= 7**, you can use the [ThreeTen Backport](http://www.threeten.org/threetenbp), a great backport for Java 8's new date/time classes. And for **Android**, you'll also need the [ThreeTenABP](https://github.com/JakeWharton/ThreeTenABP) (more on how to use it [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/38922755/7605325)).

The code below works for both.
The only difference is the package names (in Java 8 is `java.time` and in ThreeTen Backport (or Android's ThreeTenABP) is `org.threeten.bp`), but the classes and methods **names** are the same.

You could do that using a `DateTimeFormatter` with strict mode. This allows values like zero in the day and month. The other modes don't work: default mode doesn't accept zeroes, and lenient mode tries to do automatic conversions, so the strict mode is the only one that works in this case.

Then you get the individual fields (day and month) and check if they are zero. I'm using the `getLong` method (and casting to an `int`), because the `get` method (that returns an `int`) checks if the values returned are valid (so values like zero throw an exception).

Finally, you join all the pieces to get the output:

```
String valueWithDate = "00092017";
String pattern = "ddMMyyyy";
// create formatter with the pattern and strict mode
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern).withResolverStyle(ResolverStyle.STRICT);
// parse the input
TemporalAccessor parsed = fmt.parse(valueWithDate);

// get day from the parsed object
int day = (int) parsed.getLong(ChronoField.DAY_OF_MONTH);
if (day == 0) {
    day = 1;
}
// get month from the parsed object
int month = (int) parsed.getLong(ChronoField.MONTH_OF_YEAR);
if (month == 0) {
    month = 1;
}
// get year from the parsed object
int year = (int) parsed.getLong(ChronoField.YEAR_OF_ERA);

// the final value will have the same pattern? if so, just use the same formatter
String value = fmt.format(LocalDate.of(year, month, day));
System.out.println(value); // 01092017
```

So, for the input `00092017` and pattern `ddMMyyyy`, the code above will print:

> 01092017

---

As suggested by [@MenoHochschild's comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46052505/java-date-format-for-00-days-months/46055084#comment79070769_46055084), you can also use the `parseUnresolved` method, which doesn't validate the values, so it allows zero in day and month (and you don't need to set the formatter to strict mode).

This method also needs a `java.text.ParsePosition`, that is used to check for parsing errors (because it doesn't throw an exception like the `parse` method does):

```
// create formatter, no need of strict mode
DateTimeFormatter fmt = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern(pattern);
// parse
ParsePosition pos = new ParsePosition(0);
TemporalAccessor parsed = fmt.parseUnresolved(valueWithDate, pos);
// check errors
if (pos.getErrorIndex() >= 0) {
    // error in parsing (getErrorIndex() returns the index where the error occurred)
}
// rest of the code is the same
```

As [@OleV.V.'s comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46052505/java-date-format-for-00-days-months/46055084#comment79073727_46055084) suggested, you can also check if the whole input wasn't parsed, using:

```
if(pos.getIndex() < valueWithDate.length()) {
    // the input String wasn't fully parsed
}
```

---

I'm assuming that the final value will have the same format used in the input (the same pattern passed to the method).

If you want the value in another format, though, just create another formatter with a different pattern:

```
// output in another format
DateTimeFormatter output = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("MMddyyyy");
String value = output.format(LocalDate.of(year, month, day));
System.out.println(value); // 09012017
```

Comment: It seems to be illogical to allow zero day or month in strict mode. Really wondering. For a more elegant way, see this [example](https://gist.github.com/MenoData/14364a1bcd44468e705c3d6a0dab3d00).

Comment: @MenoHochschild Indeed, I also thought that *strict* should mean *I don't accept strange values*, but it actually works. Bad name choice, maybe?

Comment: Within the scope of Java-8, I suggest you consider the alternative `parser.parseUnresolved("00092017", new ParsePosition(0))` because it does not seem to depend on the irrational behaviour of resolving style.

Comment: @MenoHochschild Great, `parseUnresolved` works regardless of the resolving style. I've updated the answer, thanks a lot!

Comment: Thanks for the edit. I think that in most use cases, after `parseUnresolved()` I would want to check that the parse position indicates the entire string was parsed. This would enhance input validation.

Comment: @OleV.V. Indeed, I've added this to the answer, thanks a lot!

Comment: Sorry I was unclear, I was more thinking `pos.getIndex() < valueWithDate.length()`. @Hugo

Comment: @OleV.V. Well, I've updated the answer, thanks again!